# Windows Server: Email Notification when a user executes an exe?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

I need some way to send and email notification when a user logs in to a remote desktop and executes a exe , i need to send an email that exe was run...

Is this possible in powershell ? Should i add the email notification to task scheduler ? What is the trigger?

Advice needed on how to go about? how can powershell detect user logged in and ran an exe ? (email notification part is simple I know)

Comment: `What is the trigger?` The audit event from when the executable is run.

Comment: trigger? .. the user will login via rdp and click the shortcut on desktop to run exe... so u could say user executed

Comment: @abmv The "trigger" of the scheduled task. Setup a scheduled task that listens on the trigger from the event viewer and as an action, send your mail

Comment: @abmv: this is the point you should acknowledge you have auditing enabled and you verified the event is occurring.

Comment: Or, if that's a particular exe, you can replace it with a script which sends mail then starts original application. But I'm agree with others: you should set up auditing which will send event to audit log, and then set up monitoring of these event logs.